# Fonts in designer are different size to those at runtime

Tags: c#, silverlight, fonts

I have a Silverlight OOB application. Some of the TextBlocks (but not all) have started to behave strangely. When viewed in the Designer, they're the size I want them to be. When I run the app, they appear roughly 1pt bigger.

I've checked it with Silverlight Spy, and the font size/weight are the same as at design time. If I make the fonts too small in design mode, they come out the right size at runtime. If I use Silverlight Spy to make them 1pt too small at runtime, they look the right size. Silverlight Spy shows that the TextBlocks aren't affected by a style.

What could be causing this? I'm using VS 2010 and Silverlight 5.

Comment: You must have pressed ctrl+ or zoom !

Comment: @Sajeetharan It's just the fonts that are affected - just *some* of them. Images/Tables are unaffected. Also, this happens whichever machine the app is deployed to.

Comment: Check your windows font size! that could be the reason

Comment: "Silverlight Spy shows that the TextBlocks aren't affected by a style." - Actually they are, there's a style template for the default size/font family etc where the Setters are set. In one of your controls in question try to override the default with something like <UserControl.Resources><Style TargetType="TextBlock"><Setter Property="FontSize" Value="blah"/></Style></UserControl.Resources> and if it effects it the way you want then you need only adjust the default template or specify your own globally to override it.

Comment: @Sajeetharan It's just *some* of the fonts that are affected. This happens whichever machine the app is deployed to. Some of those machines are Apple Macs. I doubt it's an environmental thing.

Comment: @ChrisW. I tried that, and it did not have any effect.

Comment: Can you provide a tiny sample app that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I think the VS2010 designer was pretty buggy.  You should try installing a trial of 2012 or 2013 - maybe it's a bug in the designer.

Comment: Is it the same `TextBlocks` all the time? Is there perhaps a chance you've mixed "pt" and "px"?

Comment: What browser are you checking this stuff in? Is it possible you updated your browser and started getting weird behavior there? Can you see the same behavior in other browsers? I also agree with Rob that you may want to upgrade to a newer version of VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases where I have observed differences in font rendering in WPF or Silverlight, it was almost always due to the `FontFamily` being different rather than the `FontSize`.  If you can, verify with Silverlight Spy that the font families are in fact the same.

Interestingly, there can be differences even if the effective font family is the same.  In one of our applications, we are using a composite `FontFamily` definition that uses Segoe UI for most western glyph ranges, but a serifed font for the Greek glyph ranges to better differentiate those characters (this is a finance application).  I noticed that the line height was slightly different in the editor than in the runtime application.  It seems the editor doesn't always apply composite fonts correctly (or didn't, prior to some of the VS2012 updates).

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any [Transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189037%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) present.

Comment: If there were transforms, then why would it show up differently at design-time?

Comment: Well, not necessarily, but they could be influenced at runtime by bindings or storyboards. At least, Transforms are the only way for me to explain why all the inspection tools did not show unexpected font size values.

Comment: @Benjamin I've used Silverlight Spy and been through the source: altering any transforms in the project doesn't alter the size of the font, so I don't believe that this is it. Thank you though.

Comment: @TarkaDaal Okay, I've got tow more ideas what you could try to narrow down the issue: 1) remove/disable all design-time resources. 2) give the affected `TextBlock`s a fixed size.

Comment: @TarkaDaal Can you use Silverlight Spy to verify that the `FontFamily` is the same in the designer and the app?  Perhaps it's not actually a size difference, but a font loading problem.

Comment: @MikeStrobel That was it. Silverlight Spy showed that they were the same, but the fonts were different. Obvious once you mentioned it. Solution was to refer to the fonts using full class library syntax. Silverlight bug, I guess. Post this as a question, and you can have the bounty.

Comment: @TarkaDaal Oh no, did the bounty expire?

Comment: @MikeStrobel Sorry man, it did. :( I did what I could though, and you definitely deserved it.

Comment: @TarkaDaal d'oh, bad timing!  Oh well, no worries.  Thanks anyway ;).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Labels, Buttons and Checkboxes. After a look using WPF inspector, it had come to my attention that the text in each of the above contains a TextBlock to display the actual text, and I had set my default `FontSize` for a Text Block to 13 which was then overriding the value I specified for (e.g) the Label.

This sorted me out

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="LabelTemplate" TargeType="Label">
    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
</ControlTemplate>


<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter ... etc. etc. other styling I had already in here />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource LabelTemplate}" />
</Style>
```